# How to abstract routes in Hapi 17

Tags: node.js, routes, hapi.js

I'm looking at how to move our Hapi 16 application over to Hapi 17.

In particular I'm looking at how we abstract our current routing logic into separate directories and structures.

The following works, but is it right:

**server.js**

```
'use strict'

const Hapi = require('hapi')

const testRoutes = require('./routes/routes.test')
const jobRoutes = require('./routes/routes.jobs')

// Create a server with a host and port
const server = Hapi.server({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3000
})

const registerRoutes = () => {
  testRoutes.registerRoutes(server)
  jobRoutes.registerRoutes(server)
}

// Start the server
async function start () {

  try {
    await server.start()
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    process.exit(1)
  }

  console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri)
}

registerRoutes()
start()
```

**routes.test.js**

```
const testCtrl = require('../src/TestController')

exports.registerRoutes = (server) => {
  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/test/hello',
    handler: testCtrl.hello
  })

  server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/test/goodbye',
    handler: testCtrl.goodbye
  })
}
```

** TestController.js**

```
exports.hello = function (req, h) {
  return 'Hello test'
}

exports.goodbye = function (req, h) {
  return 'Goodbye test'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this way.

In Hapi.js you can treat everything like a plugin (there is a convention about it, it is not an opinion). Put your routes to separate folders and files, and struct them as plugins.

For example

```
exports.plugin = {
    async register(server, options) {
        server.route([
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/',
                options: {
                    description: 'main request handler',
                    handler: async (request, h) => {
                        return h.view('index', {'title': 'Home Page Title'});
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                method: 'GET',
                path: '/page/{id}',
                options: {
                    description: 'main request handler',
                    handler: async (request, h) => {

                        return h.view('detail_page', {'title': 'Detail Page', id: request.params.id});
                    }
                }
            },        
        ]);
    },
    version: require('../../package.json').version,
    name: 'route-main'
};
```

Now, you have a plugin that handles specific routes based on your definition in the path section. 
Just register this plugin with your server and you are good to go.

Here is sample server code.

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');

const startServer = async function() {

    const server = Hapi.Server();

    // just register your route
    await server.register({
        plugin: require('your-route-folder/and-file')
    });

    // let's say another route for only user and handles /users endpoint
    // now you can define your paths without repeating /users field on your route definition like /profile /detail/{id}
    // /users/profile, /users/detail/2
    // ref: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#-await-serverregisterplugins-options
    await server.register({
        plugin: require('your-route-folder/users'),
        options: {
            routes: {
                prefix: '/user'
            }
        }
    });


    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server started at ${server.info.uri}`);
};

startServer().catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
});
```